Has error code: ORA-28056 when using RMAN to restore table
I'm using Oracle 19c.
I have error when using RMAN to restore 1 table.
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: recoverコマンドが09/13/2024 09:24:05で失敗しました
RMAN-04006: 補助データベースのエラー: ORA-28056: Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed
ORA-28056: Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed


Login user: Administrator
Window Application Log set maxsize to 10Gb
Before backup, I was removed Application Log message
After backup, It shown Application log of RMAN backup.
I was set audit_sys_operations = FALSE, audit_sys_operations = TRUE. But same error.

How to fix this error?

I have identified the cause of the error.
Although I logged in with the Administrator account, the Oracle service did not execute with administrator privileges.
When you use RMAN to restore a database, the account that logs to the Windows Event Log is typically the Oracle service account. Specifically, it is the account under which the Oracle Database services are running.
To identify this account, you can follow these steps:

Open Services: Press Win + R, type services.msc, and press Enter.
Find Oracle services: Look for services that start with "Oracle" (e.g., OracleServiceORCL).
Check the account: Right-click on the service, select Properties, and check the Log On tab. The account listed here is the one that logs to the Windows Event Log.

If this account is Local System, Network Service, or a specific account, then that is the account performing the logging.
